# Unable to see Loading text in react hooks home page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In `React hooks` Home.js I have implemented  a `Loading...`, but I am unable to see that in Home page.  While refresh all i see in `Did not match any results!` ( *ie message displayed  for if the search is not returning any data..* )

`Home.js`

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/players');
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setIsLoading(true);
          setPlayerList(res.data.players);
          setSearchResults(res.data.players);
          const privilege = localStorage.getItem('Privilege');
          console.log("What is getting in Front End:" + privilege);
          showDeleteIcon(privilege);
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);



return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="playerList_header">
          <h1>Players</h1>
          <label>
            <div className="playerSearch_Home">
              <div className="playerSearch_Icon">
                <img alt="" src="/images/search-image-player.jpg"></img>
              </div>
              <input type="text" className="playerSearch_Home_Input" placeholder="Search players..." value={searchTerm} onChange={handleChange} />
            </div>
          </label>
        </div>
        {!searchResults.length && (<div> <p className="noSearchData"> Did not match any results! </p> </div>)}
        <div className="playerList_home_page">
        {isLoading ? (
        <div>Loading ...</div>
      ) : (
          <div className="grid-container">
            {
              searchResults.map(({ id, image, position, phonenumber, name }) => (
                <div key={id} className="grid-item">
                  {
                    deleteIcon.show && (
                      <span className="deletePlayerButton" onClick={deletePlayer(id)}>
                        <img className="deletePlayerimg" src="/images/delete.png"></img>
                      </span>
                    )}
                  <div>
                    <img alt="" className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" key={image} src={image}></img>
                  </div>
                  <div className="playerProfile_grid_border">
                    <span className="rec_name_position_data">
                      <h3 key={name}>{name}</h3>
                      <span className="playerPosition_home_tile" key={position}>{position}</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <span className="phoneNumber_home">
                    <img src="/images/phone.png" alt={"phoneTooltip.show"} key={id} name="phoneNumberhomeicon" onClick={displayPhoneToolTip(id)} />
                  </span>
                  {phoneTooltip === id && (
                    <div className="tooltip_PhoneNumber_home" key={phonenumber}>{phonenumber}</div>
                  )}
                </div>
              ))
            }
          </div>
         )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <AlertDialog
        onDelete={onDelete}
        open={deleteDialog}
        onClose={() => setDeleteDialog(false)}
        playerId={playerId}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: what is isMounted? why do you need it?

Comment: @Kerematam *"what is isMounted?"* [a bad practice](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) *"why do you need it?"* to not call `setIsLoading` and co. after the component has been unmounted.

Comment: I was getting an error earlier so read an article to use `isMounted` and error disappeared. It was few week back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loading` is supposed to be true when you call `Axios.get` but you set it true after it and then immediately set to `false`.

Try this instead:

```js
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/players');
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setPlayerList(res.data.players);
          setSearchResults(res.data.players);
          const privilege = localStorage.getItem('Privilege');
          console.log("What is getting in Front End:" + privilege);
          showDeleteIcon(privilege);
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: `if (isMounted.current) { ... }else{ setIsLoading(false); }` the sole purpose of `isMounted` is to NOT call `setIsLoading` and co after the component has been unmounted.

Comment: How can i add a small delay, may be 500 millisecond to see that...now it just flashes in the screen for a small fraction of second now...

Comment: @Thomas Right the `else` block is wrong here. Thanks I updated my code.

Answer (score 3):

You should set/unset it before and after fetch :

```js
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/players');
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setPlayerList(res.data.players);
          setSearchResults(res.data.players);
          const privilege = localStorage.getItem('Privilege');
          console.log("What is getting in Front End:" + privilege);
          showDeleteIcon(privilege);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      setIsLoading(false);
```

Comment: This should do.